# App.xaml for native application

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, resources

I have 1 dll (let's call it UI) and two applications, that can use it:
1. App1 - C# application, that uses it directly
2. App2 - C++ application that uses it through C++ CLI wrappers

I need to add some ResourceDictionaries of UI.dll to app.xaml of the App1 to work correct. 
But there is no way to do the same in App2.

Any ideas?

P.S. I need to use FindResource() function which uses app-scoped resources, that's why I need App.xaml

Comment: You would have to be a little more precise on "I need to use FindResource() function which uses app-scoped resources". Do you know that there also is a [FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx) method in FrameworkElement?

Comment: @Clemens Yes I know that. I want to call the FindResource function from the Converter class - I don't have direct access to FrameworkElement. I can pass UserControl as converter parameter but there is already one parameter, so I'll need to use MultiConverter. It will lead to the code growth, but I suppose that would be the best solution.